# Akka Source from Iterator with blocking actions

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, alpakka

The Akka documentation on `Source.fromIterator` (https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source/fromIterator.html) says:

> If the iterator perform[s] blocking operations, make sure to run it on a separate dispatcher.

I have an iterator that I want to construct an Akka `Source` from. However, it is possible for `hasNext` to return `true` before the element returned by `next` is available. If that happens, then the `next` call must block, waiting for the element. Note that `hasNext` cannot return `false`, since Akka will think the `Source` is done and stop processing.

Akka doesn't like waiting for the next element, of course. Timeout exceptions pop up occasionally. So, what do I do in this case? What does it mean to run such an iterator on a separate dispatcher? If I wrap the code in `next` to return a `Future` (using a separate dispatcher for that), then I get a `Source[Future[T]]` instead of `Source[T]`, which creates problems downstream, unless I somehow convert it to `Future[Source[T]]`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could [`mapAsync`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/mapAsync.html) do the job for you?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But how? The source in question is `Source[List[String]]`, from which the flow is directed `via` the CSV formatting transformation: `(akka.stream.alpakka.csv.scaladsl.CsvFormatting.format)`, which expects `T <: immutable.Iterable[String]` and not `Future[List[String]]` (and then, after attaching file names, to `(akka.stream.alpakka.file.scaladsl.Archive/zip)`).

Comment: Now I'm confused with what's your input and what you expect as output. Maybe you could clarify with concrete code in your post?

Comment: If you had  an `Iterator[() => Future[T]]`, you could probably use `fromIterator(...).mapAsync(x => x())` to get a `Source[T]`. Just an idea..

Comment: If you have an `Iterator[Future[T]]`, you could do `Source.fromIterator(...).mapAsync(identity)` to get a `Source[T]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you note, if you transform the iterator to be an `Iterator[Future[T]]` with something on another thread completing the futures, `Source.fromIterator` will be a `Source[Future[T]]`.  However, a `Source[Future[T]]` can always be turned into a `Source[T]` by attaching a `mapAsync(identity)`:

```
Source.fromIterator(...)  // Source[Future[T]]
  .mapAsync(identity)     // Source[T]
```

`mapAsync` does not block a thread in the stream's dispatcher.

You can also set a stage to run on a specific dispatcher using `ActorAttributes.dispatcher` and `withAttributes`:

```
Source.fromIterator(...).withAttributes(ActorAttributes.dispatcher("config.path.to.dispatcher"))
```

Note that this will introduce an async boundary (with its associated buffer) between the source and the downstream.